# White screen with black strips Ubuntu 12.04 LTS after install NVidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, software-installation, white-screen

I was trying to install Steam and it get me a message about that my NVidia drivers were outdated and they recommend me to install at least the NVidia 304 drivers, so I installed and rebooted my PC, because I'm using Ubuntu with windows 7, I select the option of Ubuntu, then I get a white screen with strips, then it turn to black with white characters and it's all, the screen freeze there, I don't even got the login screen, it was working fine before the install.

I have an NVidia geforce 7300se/7200gs.

I'm writing this with the try Ubuntu option to use the console, but I don't know how to fix this. (I'm newbie with linux and English is not my first language so i'm sorry if I wrote something wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the nvidia drivers by typing into the console:

sudo apt-get remove nvidia-304*

...then reboot once it's done ( sudo reboot ) and you will be using the open-source nvidia drivers again...

Note: You are probably better installing Ubuntu 13.10 to run Steam so you will have the newer drivers, or you could wait until April and install Ubuntu 14.04 and have the latest LTS release instead...